# systemd-udevd spams systemd-udevd[1523120]: veth20996a5: Failed to get link config: No such device

Tags: docker, logging, spam, systemd, udevd

I have setup my server logging with graylog and now I see that my logs are being spamed by level: 3 errors like these:

```
systemd-udevd[1523120]: veth20996a5: Failed to get link config: No such device
```

I think vethxxxxxxx is an interface created by Docker, but I can't figure out what is causing these errors.

Any help to solve this and find reason for these errors would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds [familiar](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16175), though afair multiple different reasons/bugs/unfortunate defaults can lead to this.